# Unclickable area in IOS Safari when the URL bar is hidden

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari

I am building a `div` that should fill the viewport, and there is some clickable element at the bottom. The Html would look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
      }

      .player-root {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
      }

      .unclickable-area {
        background-color: grey;
        color: white;
        height: 65px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="player-root">
        <div class="unclickable-area" id="unclickable">Unclickable</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script id="rendered-js">
      document.onclick = function () {
        console.log("clicked");
      };

      document.getElementById("unclickable").onclick = function () {
        alert("clicked");
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/andykao1213/pen/gOWvJom?editors=1111) reproducing this issue.

I use the `position: fixed` so the height can fill the viewport. It works fine except on the iPhone. When the device is in landscape mode and the URL bar is hidden, the `unclickable area` cannot fire any click event even though I add the event listener on the `document`.
[The demo that the area is not clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1L0.gif)

However if I swap down and make the URL bar show, the clickable area can be clicked.
[The demo that the area is clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGsfp.gif)

I think this is due to the viewport issue of IOS Safari but I cannot find and document/issue talking about this.

Reproduce version of iOS: v14.5

Answer (score 0):

So after research, I found that this issue is caused by the weird behavior of the initial containing block in mobile safari. [As this picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylbon.png), the height of the initial containing block is shorter than the viewport, which makes an area at the bottom that is not clickable. We can fix this by extending the `html` and `body` to `100vh` to fit the viewport.